# How to add a class to the next element of current element array in jquery?

Tags: jquery, addclass

I would like to know how to do such thing.

e.g. I have something like this:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="1.html">first item</a></li>
   <li><a href="2.html">second item</a></li>
   <li><a href="3.html">third item</a></li>
   <li><a href="4.html">fourth item</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to addClass to a hover a element, this is easy I do it like this:

```
$("li a").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass("show");
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass("show");
    }
);
```

However, I need to addClass to every next li element also.

So, when e.g. first **li a** eleemnt is hovering the class show2 will be added to **li a** of the second li a element.

How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$("li a").hover(
              function () {
                $(this).addClass("show").parent().next().addClass("show2");               


              },
              function () {
                $(this).removeClass("show").parent().next().removeClass("show2");

              }
            );
```

Comment: thanks this guided me in right direction with some issue that was troubling me :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) with [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to match the next anchor element.

From there, you can use [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to add the hovered element to the current set, and [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) the classes on both elements with a single call:

```
$("li a").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().find("a").add(this).toggleClass("show");
});
```

**EDIT:** The above does not take the alternate `show2` class name into account. To support it, you can do something like:

```
$("li a").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("show").parent().next().find("a").toggleClass("show2");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li a").hover(function () {
  $(this).addClass("show");
  var next_li = $(this).parent().next();
  $('a', next_li).addClass("show2");
},
function () {
  $(this).removeClass("show");
  var next_li = $(this).parent().next();
  $('a', next_li).removeClass("show2");
});
```

Although it can be written in one line.

For readability I always like to use multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by the following code (see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PUYXK/) as a proof). It will process the list of items and assign different events for each of them, based on their number within the set of elements:

```
var my_list = jQuery('ul');
my_list.find('li').each(function(index, element){
    if (index == 0){
        jQuery(this).hover(function(){
            my_list.find('li a').addClass('show');
        }, function(){
            my_list.find('li a').removeClass('show');
        });
    } else {
        jQuery(this).hover(function(){
            my_list.find('li:gt('+(index-1)+') a').addClass('show');
        }, function(){
            my_list.find('li:gt('+(index-1)+') a').removeClass('show');
        });
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** I see now I misunderstood you - my solution will add `show` class to every next element, not only the first of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery's `next` function to get the next element.

JsFiddle: jsfiddle.net/ra368sgj

```
$("li a").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass("show").parent().next().addClass("show2"); 
    },
    function () {
        $(this).addClass("show").parent().next().addClass("show2").removeClass("show2"); 
    }
);
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain your answer a little?

Comment: addClass to every next li element.

So, when e.g. first li a element is hovering the class show2 will be added to li a of the second li a element.

Comment: Add it to the answer so other people will understand what your answer is doing.

Comment: please find the js fiddle link for better understanding                                                      https://jsfiddle.net/ra368sgj/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ra368sgj/ - Js fiddle link for better understanding